# OpenCV Deploying a partial project as static or dynamic library or something else?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm fairly new to OpenCV and Visual Studio as well. My question is not so much technical but theoretically anyways:

I'm working on a bigger project but do not have access to all its subcomponents etc. I wrote a few classes and functions that other members want to use. However, I'm using some OpenCV specific things (because I'm lazy and dont want to implement everything all by myself) but the other members dont use it and they want to keep the project size relatively small.

My question is: How can I provide my code as a library or something similar that includes all my opencv dependencies? Can I create a dll of my code and just ship the opencv dlls with it? Is there a way to bundle everything into one file with only one header?

How would you solve this problem?

Summarizing: I want my functions in a library and shipped as small as possible (with opencv dependencies)

KR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your code in a DLL, and then ship OpenCV DLLs along with yours.

Or: put all your code in a DLL, and perform [static linking with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697935/lnk2005-error-linking-static-opencv-libraries-with-visual-studio-and-qt-creator).

Comment: is it possible to integrate everything into one dll?

Comment: That's what the static linking will do: one gigantic DLL.